# How to compare the basicity of 4-Aminopyridine and 1,4,5,6-Tetrahydropyrimidine

Tags: organic-chemistry

The structures of 4-Aminopyridine and 1,4,5,6-Tetrahydropyrimidine are as shown

[image]

Now the nitrogen (I) and (II) of both the compounds have their lone pair of electrons. In both cases the lone pair of electrons is currently not in resonance with the ring or other nitrogen respectively. In both the cases after protonation the (+ve) charge is stabilised by the other nitrogen through resonance. Case (A) has more resonance structures. Also Inductive effect due to nitrogen is lesser in (A) than in (B) which leads to more electron density in (A)(I). It could be argued that (A) is an aromatic amine hence less basic but aromaticity reduces the basic character due inductive effect (or maybe delocalisation of lp aswell). But in this case structure (B) has greater inductive effect (-I) due to the other nitrogen as compared to what the benzene ring would have on (A) and the lp are out of plane of ring in (A) therefore localised too.

All these effects I) Greater resonance structures II) Lesser (-I) in (A) than in (B) make me feel that (A) should be more basic however the case is completely opposite and (B) is more basic.

All that I said above could be completely wrong. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong and what is actually happening in detail. Thanks for your time!

(Note: My statement of the inductive effect of nitrogen being greater than benzene ring Is completely based on my speculation based on the fact that nitrogen is quite electronegative in general. I don't have the data to prove the same. Please correct if wrong)

EDIT: Please see my comments on the question which is linked as a duplicate to this one. I had doubts regarding the specific comparison of these two compounds based on things I've mentioned above, which is why I felt it was appropriate to make a new question to ask this in detail.

Comment: You should rather consider conjugate acids - if mesomeric structures are equivalent or not.

Comment: I think here mesomeric effect plays a greater role than inductive. There are only 2 resonance structures possible for 2nd case (the one itself) and the other being the one in which (II)N gets a negative charge. If you draw all the resonance structures of the 1st case, you will get to know that in one structure there comes a negative charge on the (I)N. But similarly the charge will be distributed at other 2 ortho positons (wrt -NH2 group). Thus the partial negative charge on (I)N will be lesser than on (II)N. This leads to the 2nd having more electron density than the 1st.

Answer (score 2):

Compare their structures after protonation. The second compound then shows two resonating structures, as given below -

[image]

Both the resonating structures are equivalent in this case, which makes the conjugate acid more stable (in the same way in which equivalent resonating structures of COO- anion makes it more stable, increasing the acidity of carboxylic acids).

For the first molecule, the lone pair donated by the top nitrogen is delocalized not only to the bottom N(I) but also to two carbons of the pyridine ring, which decreases the overall electron density on N(I) and makes it less basic.

Comment: If I'm not wrong in COO- cross resonance occurs, but in this case, its extended resonance was taking place so I thought it's becoming more stable. Since the usual idea I know is that the more it delocalizes and spreads the better it is, I heard about this partial charge method first time. If possible please provide me with some resources where I can read more about this or some other cases where this happens. Would like to learn more, (+1) for your answer though.